# EpiWebParts in EpiServer 6

Tags: episerver, episerver-6

We want to add a web part framework to our EpiServer intranet. I've found [this](https://www.coderesort.com/p/epicode/wiki/EPiWebParts#WebPartFrameworkforEPiServer) which is probably what we want. However there's no installation instructions for use under EpiServer 6 - can anyone advise on how to get started with using this framework on the current release of EpiServer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Or you could download the souce code for CMS 6 https://www.coderesort.com/svn/epicode/EPiCode.WebParts/6.x

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting it up as you would for EPiServer 5? I can't think of any obvious reasons why it wouldn't work for EPiServer 6 as well.

[Here's a post on using web parts with EPiServer](http://tedgustaf.com/en/blog/2008/8/using-web-parts-in-episerver/)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it should work the same. From CMS 5 to CMS 6 there are no breaking changes. This doesnt mean they are the same and since I am not sure how the one on coderesort works its hard for me to say. As Ted says try setting it up and post any issues you might have here and we can try to help you to the best of our knowledge.